# Creation of apps of this type is not available / fastlane produce

Tags: ios, fastlane, fastlane-produce

I'm using fastlane\produce script to make a new app, and I get the following error message:

> in `parse_response': {"data"=>nil, "messages"=>{"warn"=>nil, "info"=>nil, "error"=>["Creation of apps of this type is not available"]}, "statusCode"=>"ERROR"} (Spaceship::Client::UnexpectedResponse)

when running the script:

```
produce --username 'username' --app_identifier 'com.identifier' --app_name 'appName' --app_version 1.0.0 --sku appSKU --language English --company_name 'companyName' --skip_devcenter
```

any advise?

Answer (score 3):

found this issue in github: 
https://github.com/fastlane/spaceship/issues/103

so the problem was I had to mark the checkbox for agreeing the terms & conditions when first-time entering the iTunes \ dev center.